# Mysql fill column "reference" with strings of special format

Tags: mysql

I have a table with four columns (reference, id_category, id_product, name_category, name) and the column "reference" has both repeated values and empty values.

I want to add a string to the empty values with this format: (INITIAL OF CATEGORY NAME)(id category)-(id product)

e.g.: A26-548

And I want to add a suffix to the repeated values, like this: (REFERENCE)-(product_id)

e.g.: 420GF-2045

The problem is that most of the reference values are not repeated, and if so, I shouldn't modify them.

This is part of the table (there are more than 2000 rows):

```
reference   id_category id_product  name_category   name
            26          548         Accesorios      Jarro 200ml
            27          605         Papelillos      OCB Slim
            48          766         Herramientas    Clip LST
420GF       111         2045        420 Genetics    White Widow 100u
420GF       111         2163        420 Genetics    Cbd Blueberry 100u
420GF       111         2164        420 Genetics    Cbd Critical Mass 100u
420GF       111         2165        420 Genetics    Cbd White Widow 100u
420GF21     58          1592        Feminizadas     AMNESIA 4:20 1U
420GF21     58          1628        Feminizadas     AK 47 10U
420GF51     58          1691        Feminizadas     BLUEBERRY 420 10U
420GF51     111         2006        420 Genetics    Jack Herer 100u
420GF51     111         2015        420 Genetics    Mega Pack 100 u
AT01        95          1128        Extracciones    Atomizador
AT01        11          1648        Vaporizadores   ATMOS COMPLETE
BBF26       89          1982        Blimburn Seeds  Sour Diesel 3u
BBF26       89          2068        Blimburn Seeds  Critical Daddy Purple 3u
BSA07       121         1901        Buddha Seeds    Vesta 3u
BSA07       121         2286        Buddha Seeds    Calamity Jane 3u
```

I thought that maybe I should export the table to Excel, make the changes, and then import the table again.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following update:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT reference
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY reference
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.reference = t2.reference
SET reference = CASE WHEN t1.reference IS NULL
                     THEN CONCAT(LEFT(t1.name_category, 1), t1.id_category, '-', t1.id_product)
                     WHEN t2.reference IS NOT NULL
                     THEN CONCAT(t1.reference, '-', t1.id_product)
                     ELSE t1.reference END;
```

While this may answer your immediate question, keep in mind that as you add new data the same problem could come up again later.  You may want to change your table design.